# Trying to connect via ODBC - "The network path was not found"

Tags: asp.net, odbc

I'm trying to update a database (Oracle via ODBC) in ASP:

```
<%@ Page LANGUAGE="VB"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Configuration" %>
<%


Dim objConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ODBCNAME").ConnectionString)

'example query
Dim strSQL As String = "update foo set bar='BAZ'" 
objConn.Open()
Dim objCmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, objConn)

Try
    objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Response.Write("Record updated")
Catch e As Exception
    Response.Write(e.ToString)
End Try

%>
```

Where web.config has:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="ODBCNAME" connectionString="server=ExampleServerName;" providerName="System.Data.Odbc" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When I execute this I get the error on the objCOnn.Open() line:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found.
```

The ODBC data source is created, testing and working with other stand alone applications (closed source), and I can test the connection via the ODBC Settings, which works.

How can I connect to this database from my code? Or how can I debug this problem?

Comment: are your able to  telnet your database on the port 1433?

Comment: @शेखर I can test the oracle connection from the odbc setup on the server, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle can be a tricky beast.

First, use `OdbcConnection` instead of `SqlConnection` if you are using ODBC.

[See docs from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection(v=vs.110).aspx)

Sample code adapted from above MSDN link:

```
Private Sub InsertRow(ByVal connectionString As String)

    Dim queryString As String = _
        "INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerID, CompanyName) Values('NWIND', 'Northwind Traders')"
    Dim command As New OdbcCommand(queryString)

    Using connection As New OdbcConnection(connectionString)
        command.Connection = connection
        connection.Open()
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()

        ' The connection is automatically closed at 
        ' the end of the Using block.
    End Using
End Sub

Dim connectionString as String = <your connection details here>
InsertRow(connectionString)
```

Next, I recommend you use the Oracle Data Provider for .NET (ODP.NET, AKA `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`) which is provided with the Oracle Client (though not always installed by default; you may need to do custom install), performs better than ODBC, and is able to utilize Oracle-specific functionality. That being said, if you want to use ODBC (and there are of course some good reasons to keep it generic like this), read on:

In addition to other suggestions, make sure that the architectures match. This only applies to you if you are on a 64-bit box.

If 64-bit OS and 64-bit app you must use 64-bit ODBC to define the DSN `C:\Windows\System32\odcad32.exe`

If 64-bit OS and 32-bit app you must use 32-bit ODBC to define the DSN `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`

(Yeah, the names are REALLY confusing! `SysWOW64` basically means emulating 32-bit in a 64-bit enviro. The other problem is Microsoft named the thing `odbcad32` in the first place.. perhaps `odbcad` would be better, but they probably had to distinguish between the 32-bit and 16-bit version at the time.. just a guess)

If 32-bit OS then the location of `odbcad32.exe` is the default location (same as 64-bit on 64-bit) and is in your `PATH` by default.

If your app will run in 32-bit and 64-bit then you must define two DSNs, one for 32 and one for 64.

Alternately you can set the architecture of your project in the project settings. By default it may be `Any CPU` which (I think) means to prefer the native.. so if building on 64-bit OS you get 64-bit exe unless you change it to `x86` or something. In Visual Studio 2015 you can also use the `prefer 32-bit` checkbox.

And the same goes for the Oracle client: you must use matching architecture.

Comment: Side comment: obviously - do not put data access code in .aspx files and such. That is what code behind is for. You will get much better reuse that way. If needed, wrap your data access layers in web-friendly code and/or use business objects and object serialization to provide data from database to your web app.

Comment: security notes: use `OdbcCommand` class for passing arguments to your query. Take in consideration, that odbc uses `?` placeholders instead of named variables (`@var1`).

Comment: Good point- for folks just starting out with database-driven apps there is a lot of new ground to cover. Bind variables help protect against SQL injection, make your code cleaner, and - in Oracle's case at least - will reduce CPU usage by reducing hard parses of queries by reusing execution plans. However, the code is kept necessarily simple for demonstration purposes - since the connection is the relevant part for this question.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, I will try this in the morning, I've been absent due to illness

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use ODBC, you need to use [System.Data.Odbc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc(v=vs.110).aspx)

In addition, verify that your [Data Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx) is set properly. That will make all of the difference.

Until you try these changes, it will be difficult to provide you with much more help. Let us know what you come up with and we will be glad to help if you need it.